# Compare previous amount of posts with the new one

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to compare two values, the previous amount of posts (including `posts` and `cpt` and when there is detected an increasing amount of posts, it should set a div element on `display: block`.

I came up with the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);

$post_types = array( 'post', 'roosters', 'downloads', 'reglements', 'alv' );

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

    echo '<strong>' . $post_type . '</strong>';

    $postCountTotal = wp_count_posts($post_type)->publish;
    echo 'Total Posts: ' . $postCountTotal;
    echo '<br>';


    if ( $postCountTotal > $previous ) {
        echo 'New post detected';
    } 

    $previous = 0;
}
```

Above code will now print above echo’s. So it will return a list of `post types` that are determined at the top of the code, and add after it the total amount of posts from that `post type`.

I think I should compare the values as seen above.
First you should save the previous amount of posts or reset the increaser. Then compare the value with the new one. As you can see I made an condition - if statement - to compare the previous value with the new one. Only now for every `post type` it will return a echo of “New post detected”, also if there are no new posts detected.

In short, compare the previous value with the new one. If detected an increasing of the amount, set a div element `display: block` for two days for example.

I look out for your response!

Comment: Did you run the code to see what happened? Do you actually have a problem, or do you just want us to code review (in which case, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Yes it will respons a list of CPT as seen above. And add the amount of total posts of that post type after it. I will update my question with it, to make it more detailed.

Comment: You are comparing $previous  without first giving it a value

Comment: where do you overwrite the $previous value so it will work with future runs?

Comment: I tried above code, but this isn’t the right code. I don’t know how to save first the previous value, so I can compare this with the new one.

Comment: @alexalex I thought I should set the `$previous` variabel to zero for reset the value, but this isn’t correctly I think.

Comment: @Caspert: you'll probably have to get that value from the database, maybe save it in the options table and get it from there, compare the value you have in the databse with the $postCountTotal value see if there are differences if there are output your message and update the databse value, if this sounds good I'll edit a response, just let me know

Comment: @alexalex Yes I think that’s a great solution. And only if it is increased, than add some css to a div element for some days, but that’s for later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the database to be able to compare values from one run to another run of the script, please check in line comments

```
$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);

$post_types = array( 'post', 'roosters', 'downloads', 'reglements', 'alv' );

foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {

    echo '<strong>' . $post_type . '</strong>';

    $postCountTotal = wp_count_posts($post_type)->publish;
    echo 'Total Posts: ' . $postCountTotal;
    echo '<br>';

    //first we read the previous post count value from the databse so we can compare the old value with the new one EDIT: use 0 as the default value if no data in database -first run
    $previous = get_option( 'postContTotal', 0 );
    if ( $postCountTotal > $previous ) {
        echo 'New post detected';
        //if the number of posts increased then save this new value for future compares
        update_option( 'postContTotal', $postCountTotal );
    } 
}
```

extra info about [WordPress Options api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API).

Comment: I uploaded the code, but it doesn’t echo the text ’New post detected’ if I add a new post to the site. Should we not use the `add_option` function of the API to declared the variable `postCountTotal ` in the database first?

Comment: I update the code to this: http://snippi.com/s/di4s4t0 I edited the DB name to lowercases, if I read the codex of `add_option`. Also add the `add_option` function. Now it will show a message when there is a new post detected, only, if you delete a post and after that create a new one, it doesn’t display the echo, it will saved the last total amount, so we should make also an update function that determine deleted posts.

Comment: Currently trying to get it work. If I take a look at the code, then the `update_option` will only be fired when the `$postCountTotal` is greater then `$previous`. Should we not update it also outside the if statement or is this incorrect?

Comment: please read documentation for update_option, it will create the option if it doesn't exists, no need of using add_option, using add_option will add extra rows to your database :(, you'll have to delete all your database entries and start over sorry; please read documetnation, please check the database while running the script to understand the changes that occur

Comment: I followed your advice. Indeed the it will automatically create a new table row for the post amount. Only, when I delete a post, the counter will not decrease his value. So the db isn’t update.

Comment: well in your question you said you wanted to check only if the count increased, to check for any changes use: if ($postCountTotal != $previous ) this way it will run the code on any post number changes

Comment: Your right. Sorry for that. Thank you I will test if it will working!